# How to "downgrade" a Keras/Tensorflow model so older code can work with it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm quite new to Keras and Tensorflow, and I'd like to export my model to Javascript to be able to run it in a web browser. This worked great with [WebDNN](https://mil-tokyo.github.io/webdnn/docs/tutorial/keras.html) a year ago.

Today I updated my Tensorflow installation and ran the whole model again. Unfortunately, I'm now getting the error

```
NotImplementedError: WebDNN supports TensorFlow >=v1.2.0,<=v1.4.0 Currently, TensorFlow 1.13.1 is installed.
```

**How can I "downgrade" my model data to the Tensorflow 1.4.0 format so that it runs with WebDNN?**

Should I create a new Anaconda environment, install Tensorflow 1.4.0 there, and move the model weights to that environment? Or should I try to adapt the code of WebDNN so that it works with TensorFlow 1.13?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0`.

It is good practice to install your dependencies in separate environments, to avoid global pollution.